# No notification message for Triage custodian badge

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges, notifications, triage

I did some review tasks from the new Triage queue, and so received a new Custodian badge. But I  didn't receive a notification message saying I received that badge.

Answer (score 14):

You don't receive notifications for certain bronze badges once you reach the 'association bonus' reputation level; you are considered a veteran now. *Custodian* is such a badge.

See [Prevent the 'Notification Fiesta'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96951/prevent-the-notification-fiesta) and [Which badges do not cause a notification for experienced users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138113/which-badges-do-not-cause-a-notification-for-experienced-users)